# Set promotes Rule to RuleDelayed?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, assignment, replacement

In mentally building a model of how Mathematica works, I naively expected `Set` to create a `Rule` in a symbol's `DownValues`, and `SetDelayed` to create a `RuleDelayed` in a symbol's `DownValues`. Therefore, I was a bit surprised when I tested

```
ClearAll[g];
Set[g[5], 0];
SetDelayed[g[x_], 1];
DownValues[g] // FullForm
```

and saw

```
List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[g[5]],0],RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[g[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]],1]]
```

I naively expected to see

```
List[Rule[HoldPattern[g[5]],0],RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[g[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]],1]]
```

or even

```
List[Rule[g[5],0],RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[g[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]],1]]
```

The extra `HoldPattern` and `RuleDelayed` seem semantically harmless -- at least I wasn't able to think of a breaking example before breakfast.  Looking into the issue, I find the following remarks in [the documentation for `HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldPattern.html) (emphases are mine)

> The left-hand sides of rules are **usually** evaluated, as are **parts of** the left-hand sides of assignments. You can use HoldPattern to stop any part from being evaluated.

The ambiguity of that statement signals that there is a whole lot more going on, here, meaning `Set` and `SetDelayed` aren't going to be exactly equivalent to the rules one would naively expect, and there must be special cases and exclusions in the works.

I'd be grateful for hints, experiences, opinions, deeper knowledge, suggested experiments, and especially pointers to clarifying documentation.

Comment: Since @Rojo already gave an extended answer, I'd just add that IMO the essential part can be summarized very briefly: rules in the rule base must be as inert as they can possibly be, so that no part of them evaluates prematurely. This is why `HoldPattern` is used for the l.h.s., and `RuleDelayed` to keep the r.h.s. also unevaluated until the replacement is made. Also, as @Rojo noted, this is not always enough, and some evaluation of the l.h.s. does happen during assignments (which was obviously an intentional design decision).

Comment: I gave a more extended analysis of evaluation during assignments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de), you may find it interesting as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `Set` and `SetDelayed` give `RuleDelayed` values. So, if you do

```
x=y;
y=2;
Hold[x]/.OwnValues[x]
```

> Hold[y]

That's because `OwnValues` evaluates to what you originally stored, and at the time you did the setting, `y` didn't have any values and `x=y`. If the values were stored with `Rule`, you would get, instead of

```
OwnValues[x]

{HoldPattern[x] :> y}
```

this

```
{HoldPattern[x] -> 2}
```

It surely can be stored as a `Rule`, but you would have a difficult time trying to look at the values without them getting evaluated into something they are not.

The (not) only difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` can be shown in the following equivalence

```
x:=y
```

is (not)  the same as

```
x=Unevaluated[y]
```

So, before storing the values, `Set` evaluates them, while `SetDelayed` doesn't. The "not" are because this is not the whole story, but the 99.9% of the story. There is the subtletly that you can't do `x:={1, 2, 3}`, `x[[2]]=8` as it was asked in a previous question. Also, for some reason Mathematica stores the information on how you did the assignment also for `DownValues` and the rest, memory storage isn't exactly the same, etc. A little bit of an "advanced" mistery that you shouldn't worry about...

As to the left hand sides:

Both `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` evaluate the left hand side. So, if you want your definition to be stored (and seen when you type `XValues[symbol]`) as they were at definition time, then you have to store them inside `HoldPattern`. Thus, you can do something like

```
highInteger = _Integer?(# > 234 &);

f[i : highInteger] := 2 i

ClearAll@highInteger
```

and still have this working

```
f[634]
```

> 1268

As to the "as are parts of the left hand sides of assignments" part, this is in the docs.
Both `Set` and `SetDelayed` evaluate their left hand sides' heads AND arguments, but don't perform a transformation of that result before doing the assignment. So,

x = y;
y[2] = z;

Now, what do you think the next assignment will do?

x[2] = 98;

Prrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.....

```
DownValues@y
```

> {HoldPattern[y[2]] :> 98}

```
DownValues@x
```

> {}

```
DownValues@z
```

> {}

Comment: I just tried `ClearAll[f,x];f[x_]=x^2` then the undocumented `Language``ExtendedFullDefinition[f]`, which shows `{HoldPattern[f[x_]]->x^2}`, namely `Rule`, but `DownValues[f]` continues to show `{HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>x^2}`, rule delayed.  Wheels within wheels.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, the result of that function is wrapped in `Language`DefinitionList` which has attribute `HoldAll`, so you don't need `RuleDelayed` any more to allow you to see what's really stored

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Very interesting, thank you. I already asked for such functionality (at least [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5919284/590388) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5840313/590388)). How did you find the ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` function? How it differs from ``Language`ExtendedDefinition``?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov try `??Language\`*` -- that's how I found `Language\`ExtendedFullDefinition`.  Not sure how it differs from `Language\`ExtendedDefinition`